# Dismiss Modal view on Popover row selected in iphone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I present a modal view on a button Tapped.

In that view, I made a new view(extra view). In Extra view, i have a `UITableView` & a `UIButton`.

When i click on that button,i open a view (Leftview) in popOVer.Now, i want to dismiss the "Extraview" on click of leftView's Table row.

MY code is as follow:

```
// Leftside view:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissModal"object:nil];

}

// Presented modal view.m


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissModal:) name:@"DismissModal" object:nil];
}


-(void)dismissModal:(NSNotification *)notif
{

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**My error is as follow:**

[Reader_View dismissModal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb494e10 2013-01-08 16:12:00.468 AFFeedsReader[3449:1d903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Reader_View dismissModal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb494e10

Comment: @Dinesh, i post my code..

Comment: @user1673099 can u give me your popoverview controller name?

Comment: leftside view which contains a table view

Comment: Why is it in `viewDidLoad`? I believe your error could be here your trying to dismiss a modal view controller that I don't think has even appeared yet and this is why it is throwing an error. Not 100% so not added as an answer. Try moving it to somewhere like `viewDidAppear` or something. Something that runs when your view has actually appeared.

Comment: but the view is already appeared & in that i open a popview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by implementing post notification.

Answer (score 1):

In your "Leftview.h", do the below

```
@protocol DismissingDelegate

- (void) dismissextra;

@end
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DismissingDelegate>delegate;
```

When initializing your leftview, assign the delegate to the ViewController that shows the modal one.

In that controller, define it as a "DismissingDelegate", and implement the below method:

```
- (void) dismissextra {
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: in the .h file initialization as per below:

`#import "Leftview.h"
@interface classname : superclassname <DismissingDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

Please Do not use Notifications for Simple tasks as it consumes much resources ...so kindly go with any delegate method available always..unless there is a real need of getting notifications on the whole of the app..